# AIX operating system versions?

Tags: aix

I need to understand the verions, patches, releases under each type of AIX OS. Any document or link to refer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AIX has a number of major releases.  The current ones are 5.3, 6.1 and 7.1.  Major releases have increased in frequency over the last few years, my perception is that IBM are moving them in-line with their Power processor versions (Power7 is current).

Within a major release, there are technology levels (TL's).  A new TL is released once per year and includes support for new hardware as well as fixes.  Throughout the year, each TL also has Service Packs (SP's).  Service Packs only include fixes.  IBM aims for four SP's per year.  Each TL is supported for approximately 3 years, so will receive SP's for it's entire life.

[This page](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/support/release_strategy.html) has the full strategy.

Comment: Much appreciate the help EightBitTony. This is infact very very useful and has served the purpose.

Comment: Happy to help, don't forget to mark this as an answer if you feel it has met your question.

Answer (score 0):

Was google broken for you? [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIX) is a link to the wikipedia page about overall version but you'll need to look on ibm.com to find out about patches & releases, who else would have 25 years of detailed OS information to hand?